# Laravel API Authentication (Passport), Get user ID from a post application/json

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

My client is send a post application/json that has a accessToken in the json file. How do I verify the user and get the user id?

Here is my api.php file:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
/* API Routes */

Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
   return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:api');

Route::post('/client', function (Request $request) {
    $data = $request->json()->all();
    return $data;
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

In the $data array i can see the accessToken.

```
[user] => Array
  (
    [accessToken] => iOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6I...
  )
```

It send back HTTP 401 : Unauthorized

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: I was think I would just add the accessToken like this:
$jsonArray = json_decode(json_encode($data),true);

$accesstoken = $jsonArray['session']['user']['accessToken'];

$request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');

$request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer '.$accesstoken);

But how would I send this to get the user ID need?

Answer (score 2):

Is your client able to send the access token in the header?

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

If so, you can use the `auth:api` that you already have in your code, here you can see how to call it with an example using Guzzle:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#protecting-routes

```
$response = $client->request('GET', '/api/user', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
    ],
]);
```

Otherwise, and against my advice because it's more standard and secure to use the heather Authorization, you may have two (not very appropriate) alternatives:

1. You can create a middleware to check if there is no Authorization in the heather, but in the body, and if so, move it to the heather before the `auth:api` middleware (but be sure to run this middleware first).
2. Remove the `auth:api` middleware and authenticate either creating your own middleware or in the controller itself.

Documentation about Laravel's middleware:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

Here you can find more info about Laravel's out of the box authentication:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

Note: Be sure that the documentation version and your Laravel's version match.

More info about Barer Authentication:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication

This is an example (not tested) of how the middleware could work:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class BodyAuthenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure                 $next
     * @param  string|null              $guard
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()
            && null !== ($token = $request->json('access.user.accessToken', null))) {
            $request->headers->add([
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            ]);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

You can also have a look at the Passport Middleware code here:

https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/5.0/src/Http/Middleware/CreateFreshApiToken.php

You have different ways to register your middleware:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#registering-middleware

So you have to edit this file:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php

Depending on your API needs, you may do something like:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...

    'auth.body' => \App\Http\Middleware\BodyAuthenticate::class,
];
```

And then you can add this middleware in your route:

```
Route::post('/client', function (Request $request) {
    $data = $request->json()->all();
    return $data;
})->middleware('auth.body', 'auth:api');
```

Or make something more global (if all API calls require token auth) adding the middlewares to the api middleware group (in within `App\Http\Kernel` Class too):

```
'api' => [
    'throttle:60,1',
    'bindings',
    'auth.body',
    'auth:api',
],
```

Then, if the token sent match with any token in your database, the auth singleton will return the user who owns it. You can get that user like:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

// Get the currently authenticated user...
$user = Auth::user();

// Get the currently authenticated user's ID...
$id = Auth::id();
```

Keep in mind that the client has to send the token in every single call (is not a session).

So you can protect the routes:

1. As the doc suggest (in the route or the controller):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#protecting-routes

```
Route::get('client', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth.body', 'auth:api');
```

Or in the controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth.body', 'auth:api');
}
```

2. With a group route:

```
    Route::middleware(['auth.body', 'auth:api'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('client', function () {
            // Uses first & second Middleware
        });

        Route::post('client', function (Request $request) {
            // Uses first & second Middleware
            $data = $request->json()->all();
            return $data;
        });

        Route::get('client/user/profile', function () {
            // Uses first & second Middleware
        });
    });
```

3. If you edited `App\Http\Kernel` to add the middlewares globally (you don't need a group):

```
    Route::get('client', function () {
        // Uses first & second Middleware
    });

    Route::post('client', function (Request $request) {
        // Uses first & second Middleware
        $data = $request->json()->all();
        return $data;
    });

    Route::get('client/user/profile', function () {
        // Uses first & second Middleware
    });
```

Tip: you can use the groups to add, not only `middleware` but also other interesting parameters such as controllers `namespace`, `domain`, naming alias prefix with `as`, or URI `path` prefix.

Example:

```
    Route::group([
        'namespace'  => 'Client', // Loads from App\Http\Controllers\Client
        'domain'     => 'client.domain.com',
        'as'         => 'client::', // Check with `php artisan route:list --name=client`
        'middleware' => ['auth.body', 'auth:api'],
        'prefix'     => 'api',
    ], function () {
        // Uses first & second Middleware
        // GET https://client.domain.com/api/
        Route::get('/', function () {
            // ...
        });

        // Uses first & second Middleware
        // GET https://client.domain.com/api/profile
        Route::get('client/profile', function () {
            $user = Auth::user();
            // ...
        });

        // Uses first & second Middleware
        // POST https://client.domain.com/api/profile
        Route::post('client/profile', function (Request $request) {
            // ...
        });

        // Uses first & second Middleware
        // App\Http\Controllers\Client\PhotoController
        // @link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers
        // GET          /photos                 index   photos.index
        // GET          /photos/create          create  photos.create
        // POST         /photos                 store   photos.store
        // GET          /photos/{photo}         show    photos.show
        // GET          /photos/{photo}/edit    edit    photos.edit
        // PUT/PATCH    /photos/{photo}         update  photos.update
        // DELETE       /photos/{photo}         destroy photos.destroy
        Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');

        //...
    });
```

Notice that, if you edited `App\Http\Kernel` to add the middlewares globally, you don't need the `middleware` in the group array.

Comment: Thanks for responding. my client can't put the access token in the header. I have check and there is no authorization in the header.

Comment: Is there away to use passport and just send the access token to it? I am new to laravel and passport any help would be great.

Comment: I edited the response so you can see how the middleware option could work. Could that work for you?

Comment: I change the json to be 'access.user.accessToken'.   So how would I call this now?    Put back the auth:api?   How should I do my route?

Comment: I let you the links to figure that part out, as it depends on your project needs, but I edited the response to:

    1. The json is updated to `access.user.accessToken`
    2. How to add the middleware for a single route or as part of the API group.

Comment: I added the 'auth.body' to my kernal.php. Change my route so it uses the ->middleware('auth.body', 'auth:api');. I can see the header was added. (thanks). Now I am trying to still get my user id or client id. Tried the $response = $client->request('GET', '/api/user', ... you had at the beginning but is gives me a Undefined variable: client. What am I miss. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I added, not only how to get the id `Auth::id()`, but the user `Auth::user()`. However, confirm that you followed all the [Laravel Passport installation steps](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#installation), and that you migrated correctly the database, so you have the [oauth tables](https://github.com/laravel/passport/tree/5.0/database/migrations), and that the token you are sending, exists in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks To Gonxalo and fwartner See:https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-with-passport-get-current-user-with-personal-access-token

If the Access Token is Not in your header then do what Gonxalo says above.

Then add fwartner suggestion to get your user id.

The Alexa Skill doesn't send the accessToken in the header it send it in the body. I hope this helps someone down the road.

Here is my api.php:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
/*
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:api');

Route::post('/alexa', function (Request $request) {

    $data = $request->json()->all();
    $jsonArray = json_decode(json_encode($data),true);

    $user = auth()->guard('api')->user();

    $userid =$user->id;
    $JsonOut = GetJsonResponse();
    return $JsonOut;
})->middleware('auth.body', 'auth:api');

function GetJsonResponse(){
    $NextNumber = 1;
    $EndSession  = "true";
    $SpeakPhrase = "Alexa Success.";


    $ReturnValue= '
    {
      "version": "1.0",
      "sessionAttributes": {
        "countActionList": {
          "read": true,
          "category": true,
          "currentTask": "none",
          "currentStep": '.$NextNumber.'
        }
      },
      "response": {
        "outputSpeech": {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "text": "' . $SpeakPhrase . '"
        },
        "reprompt": {
          "outputSpeech": {
            "type": "PlainText",
            "text": "Say next item to continue."
          }
        },
        "shouldEndSession": ' . $EndSession . '
      }
    }';
    return $ReturnValue;
}
```

Also, I added a header to the BodyAuthenticate.php middleware

$request->headers->add(['Accept' => 'application/json' ]);
   $request->headers->add(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token, ]);